# yii2 - How to make checkbox visible with conditional logic

Tags: php, checkbox, yii2, conditional-statements, visible

I need help to make my checkbox visible if the status is 3.

Here my view code :

```
//Checkbox
            [
              'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
              'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 50px'],
              'checkboxOptions'=> function($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return ["value" => $model->ACCOUNT_ID];
              },
              'visible' => $model->STATUS_INSTALLMENT == 3
            ],
```

I run that code and it cause my checkbox disappear.

Comment: then that means $model->STATUS_INSTALLMENT == 3 is false

Comment: how to make $model->STATUS_INSTALLMENT == 3 as a true condition?

Comment: Visible is checkBoxColumn property not for single checkbox, you need to write style to hide checkbox or disable them.

Comment: How about the logic to hide or show the checkbox with style.

Comment: No experience with yii, so I can't say this code makes sense, but I can give some debugging suggestions: put `var_dump($model->STATUS_INSTALLMENT);` somewhere to see the value of it. Maybe it's not 3 in this case ;). And maybe it will return a `(string) "3"` instead of `(int) 3`? It's better to use `===` and make sure `$model->STATUS_INSTALLMENT` is an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
['class' => '\yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
   'checkboxOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
        if ($model->STATUS_INSTALLMENT == 3) {
            return ['value' => $key];
        }
        return ['style' => ['display' => 'none']]; // OR ['disabled' => true]
    },
],
```

Comment: This actually is not a good answer, as it does not work properly, when using "select all" checkbox. To hide the checkbox, you should use `['disabled' => true, 'style' => ['display' => 'none']]`. This way, it is not visible AND disabled, so it won't be selected by select all logic.